I’m encountering a recurring issue with user logins Session
I have added approximately 100 users to my website, each with a unique username and password. However, I’m encountering a recurring issue with user logins.
Occasionally, when a user logs in with their credentials, instead of being redirected to their user dashboard, they are redirected to the admin panel with full access to the site. It's as if they logged in as the admin, even though the admin has a different email and username.
For example, a user with the username "abc" will enter their credentials, but instead of logging in as "abc," they will be logged in as my admin account, which has the username "123."
This issue occurs randomly and only affects some users at unpredictable times. Could you please help me resolve this?
i am using Plugin named as ( persistent Login) which keep wordpress users sessions for 1 year

the question you ask first is here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/427250/user-with-subscriber-role-automatically-logs-in-as-admin-in-wordpress-body. you can find it by clicking on your profile image in the top bar.
